# Parse-related frameworks 'missing' after converting to Xcode 7.0/Swift 2.0

Tags: parse-platform, swift2, xcode7

Scenario: 
1) Xcode workspace with CocoaPods.
2) CocoaPods contains:
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit' 
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'

Xcode 6.4/Swift 1.2 build okay.

But after converting to Swift 2.0 and did a rebuild via Xcode 7.0, the objc/swift bridge file fail to show the frameworks.  Each linked framework is 'invisible':

[image]

Why did this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm still in Xcode 6.4 and noticed the same thing today.  Not sure when the problem began as I haven't been in this project for about a month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your framework search paths.  I was having this problem and someone suggested adding $(SRCROOT) to the framework search paths as a fix.  I tried that and it did fix the issue, but it wasn't what was really causing my particular problem.  I discovered later that in my framework search paths I had a reference to my own project which had become invalid because I renamed the parent folder my project was in.  I noticed later I had a warning about it, and when I fixed the bad folder name I found that I no longer needed the $(SRCROOT) and it still worked.  Apparently the only thing it was needed for was Parse's framework.